# farthest distance from a point to a polygon in python

Tags: python, coordinates, polygon, point, shapely

In order to determine a radius to draw a circle that goes through the farthest point of a polygon given the centroid, I would like to determine the radius given the centroid (`point_geometry`) and the polygon (`polygon_geometry`). in `python`.

[image]

From a given polygon (independently on the shape, the centroid will be used).

```
from shapely import geometry
from haversine import haversine
polygon = geometry.Polygon([[0, 0], [0.5, 0], [0.6, 1], [0, 1], [-0.5, 0.5]])
```

I compute the maximum distance from the centroid as follows:

```
np.max([haversine(point_border,list(polygon.centroid.coords)[0]) for point_border in polygon.exterior.coords])
```

This function is measuring the harvesine distance from the centroid to every point of the polygon exterior points.

is there any other shorter/fast way?

Comment: Only solution I can think of right now, is to calculate the vector to each polygon edge from your centroid and then use the Pythagorean theorem to find the longest distance by comparing the vector length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from shapely import geometry

polygon = geometry.Polygon([[0, 0], [0.5, 0], [0.6, 1], [0, 1], [-0.5, 0.5]])

centroid = polygon.centroid
vertex = polygon.exterior.coords

#calculate all distances from centroid to polygon vertex
distances=[geometry.LineString([centroid, v]).length for v in vertex]

print(f"Max distance: {max(distances)}")
>>>Max distance: 0.6734969118546704
```

Comment: good approach, mine seems to be faster, but this is more readable for the user. Let's see if there are other solutions, so I will benchmark all them in order to provide a comparisson.